# Adding a candidate view for a keyboard app

Tags: android

[this the keyboard which I created up to now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLz5G.png)

But I don't know how 
[to make a view like this (marked in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVd5p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

first of all make a layout for predictions whatever you want

after that in you keyboard class override this method `onCreateCandidatesView()`

in this method return your view

```
@Override
public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
        candidateView = new CandidateView(this);    
        mCandidateView = candidateView.getCandidateView();
        setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        return mCandidateView;
}
```

here CandidateView is a class which is inflating  layout

Comment: I create a layout for the candidate view but I don't have an idea about how candidateView  class is implemented

Comment: you have to make your own class

Comment: can you give me a source code for layout, candidateView class, Keyboard class